# kafka __consumer_offsets and unclean shutdown?

Tags: apache-kafka

I was wondering can anyone explain how actually `__consumer_offsets` works?
For testing purposes I have single instance of kafka  0.11.0.0 With these overridden settings:

```
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
broker.id=0
offsets.retention.minutes=43200
log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms=60000
log.retention.hours=720 
log.flush.interval.ms=60000
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
```

And I have a single consumer called `pigeon`.

Everything works fine, untill I do a `kill -9` on kafka server (unclean shutdown). After that it seems that the client looses offset.

#### Before the `kill -9`:

Log from the client (using `kafka-reactive`):

```
2017-10-12 13:08:32.960 [DEBUG] o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - Group pigeon committed offset 275620 for partition ClusterEvents-0
```

Looking at `ConsumerGroupCommand`:

```
# ./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand --bootstrap-server localhost:9092  --group pigeon --new-consumer --describe`
TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
ClusterEvents                  0          275620          275620          0          pigeon-1507813552573-b3c74e75-04c1-48d0-bf5a-b66c203861aa/10.84.2.238                   pigeon-1507813552573
```

And looking at `__consumer_offsets`:

```
#./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic __consumer_offsets --from-beginning --formatter "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter" | grep pigeon
[pigeon,ClusterEvents,0]::[OffsetMetadata[264458,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1507285596838,ExpirationTime 1509877596838]
<.....>
[pigeon,ClusterEvents,0]::[OffsetMetadata[275620,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1507813712886,ExpirationTime 1510405712886]
```

So the `__consumer_offsets` first offset is `264458` and we can see that `275620` offset is committed

#### After `kill -9`:

Now let's do a `kill -9` on kafka process, while kafka is down, stop the consumer and after kafka restarts let's look at the same data:

```
# ./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand --bootstrap-server localhost:9092  --group pigeon --new-consumer --describe`
TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
ClusterEvents                  0          264458          275645          11187      -                                                 -                              -


#./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic __consumer_offsets --from-beginning --formatter "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter" | grep pigeon
[pigeon,ClusterEvents,0]::[OffsetMetadata[264458,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1507285596838,ExpirationTime 1509877596838]
<.....>
[pigeon,ClusterEvents,0]::[OffsetMetadata[275620,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1507813712886,ExpirationTime 1510405712886]
```

So although `__consumer_offsets` contains same info that offset is `275620` commited, but `ConsumerGroupCommand` reports that the current offset is `264458`. Why?

How does `__consumer_offsets` actually work?

If I restart the consumer, it will start consuming from offset `264458`, commit the latest offset, and I can do a kill -9 on kafka again, and it will start consuming from `264458`

Am I misunderstanding how this should work? At first I though that this is due to log changes not being fsynced to the disk, so i decreased
`log.flush.interval.ms` to `60s`, and waited for couple of minutes between kills. But that does not seem to help. And since `__consumer_offsets` contains much greater commiteed value, why does after unclean shutdown set offset to `264458`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was an issue with kafka 0.11.0.0 and 0.11.0.1 fixes that.

More info [[KAFKA-5600] - Group loading regression causing stale metadata/offsets cache](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5600)